# Ember fire filter data in controller

Tags: firebase, ember.js, emberfire

I'm new to ember, what I've created is a task manager app in Ember. I've got a model for tasks which is the following:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    location: DS.attr('string'),
    date: DS.attr('date'),
    archive: DS.attr('boolean'),
});
```

I've also got it to show all the tasks for this model in a tasklist page. However I'm currently having issues of filtering only the tasks where archive is not equal to true.

In my tasklist route I've got this to pull through my task

```
model: function () {    
        return this.store.findAll('task');   
    }
```

However i need this to filter all tasks where archive is equal to false. I do I add this here or into my controller.

*Updated*

I've added this to my controller:

```
filteredModel: Ember.computed('model', function(){
        let model = this.get('model');

        return model.filter(function(item){
            return item.data.archive == false;
        });

    }),
```

This kind of work, so its displaying a filtered list however when I add a new item to the list it doesnt update the list, with the new item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce the computed property in controller which will return the filtered taskList,

```
notArchivedTask: Ember.computed.filterBy('model','archive',false)
```

Comment: I added this to my controller and updated my each loop to incorporate the notArchivedTask as the model, however, displayed the view with no data at all

Comment: In your updated code you need to include dependant key `model.[]` so that this will recalculated every add/remove item.

Comment: would you be able to demonstrate in an answer

Comment: You can refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46211471/5771666) and its twiddle link

Comment: How are you updating model ? Use `set` method, only then computed property will be recalculated

Comment: Well when i add a job i use a `createRecord` and `save`

Comment: When I used the `model.[]` it only shows one record in my listing

Comment: Never mind i released it was a bug in my code, this worked great thank you